# Is there a way to translate documents in a batch without passing the source the source language code in Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to build a solution that should process batch documents which are in multiple languages. As per the Google documentation, it accepts list of documents but the source language code is mandatory and it accepts only one language code.

I want the application to be global and translate the batch documents auto detecting the language. Please suggest if there is any alternative to perform this action using cloud Translation API.

Below is the code from Google Documentation

from google.cloud import translate_v3beta1 as translate

def batch_translate_document(
input_uri: str,
output_uri: str,
project_id: str,
timeout=180,
):

```
client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

# The ``global`` location is not supported for batch translation
location = "us-central1"

# Google Cloud Storage location for the source input. This can be a single file
# (for example, ``gs://translation-test/input.docx``) or a wildcard
# (for example, ``gs://translation-test/*``).
# Supported file types: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/supported-formats
gcs_source = {"input_uri": input_uri}

batch_document_input_configs = {
    "gcs_source": gcs_source,
}
gcs_destination = {"output_uri_prefix": output_uri}
batch_document_output_config = {"gcs_destination": gcs_destination}
parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

# Supported language codes: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/language
operation = client.batch_translate_document(
    request={
        "parent": parent,
        "source_language_code": "en-US",
        "target_language_codes": ["fr-FR"],
        "input_configs": [batch_document_input_configs],
        "output_config": batch_document_output_config,
    }
)

print("Waiting for operation to complete...")
response = operation.result(timeout)

print("Total Pages: {}".format(response.total_pages))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to detect the language, and then to use this detected language for your translation. You can use the [detectLanguage API operation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations/detectLanguage)

However, you can't perform batch translation with different source language. Only one is supported, and you can batch several contents.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response guillaume blaquiere. Can you please suggest what are the repercussions if I use  synchronous online processing while looping through each one of the batch documents, such as  pricing, latency etc.,?

Comment: I can't answer you. The pricing is based on the number of character that you process, to detect the language and to translate the text: https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing. If you detect the language for each text to translate, you double your initial cost. And you add one API call latency (about 200ms, roughly) per text translated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and suggestions.